# How to submit a asp.net page for search using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, repeater

I have an ASP.net (`www.mypage.com/search.aspx`) page which has some dropdownlist (populated from code-behind), a submit button and a repeater control:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCount"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddlProvider" CssClass="setProvDDStyle" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddlSpecialty" CssClass="chosen-select setProvDDStyle" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddlLocation" CssClass="chosen-select setProvDDStyle" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Search" />

<~- was using the below button to handle the search
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbSearch" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="defaultLinks" runat="server" OnClick="lbSearch_Click">Search</asp:LinkButton> -->

<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptSearchResult" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div style="padding-left: 5%; overflow: hidden; width: 95%;">
            <div style="float: left; width: 20%; overflow: hidden; text-align: center;">
                <img src="<%# Eval("Image").ToString() %>" />
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; width: 78%; overflow: hidden; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <span><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"><%# Eval("Physician Name").ToString() %></asp:Label></span>
                <hr />
                Specialty: <asp:Label id="lblSpec1" runat="server"><%# Eval("Specialty1").ToString() %></asp:Label>, 
            </div>
        </div>
    </HeaderTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The following code behind:

```
string cString;
SqlConnection Conn;
string sqlCode = "";
string strGender = "";
int rowCount = 0;
string strProv, strSpec, strLoca, strGend, strInsu, strLang;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cString = ""; //my connection string
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulatePhysician();
        PopulateLocation();
        PopulateSpecialty();
        PopulateInsurance();
        PopulateLanguage();
    }
}
public void lbSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Conn = new SqlConnection(cString);
    Conn.Open();

    strGender = ddlGender.SelectedItem.Text;

    if (ddlProvider.SelectedItem.Text == "Any Provider")
    {
        strProv = "%";
    }
    else
    {
        strProv = ddlProvider.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
    if (ddlSpecialty.SelectedItem.Text == "Any Specialty")
    {
        strSpec = "%";
    }
    else
    {
        strSpec = ddlSpecialty.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
    if (ddlLocation.SelectedItem.Text == "Any Location")
    {
        strLoca = "%";
    }
    else
    {
        strLoca = ddlLocation.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
    if (ddlGender.SelectedItem.Text == "Any Gender")
    {
        strGend = "%";
    }
    else
    {
        strGend = ddlGender.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
    if (ddlInsurance.SelectedItem.Text == "Any Insurance")
    {
        strInsu = "%";
    }
    else
    {
        strInsu = ddlInsurance.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
    if (ddlLanguage.SelectedItem.Text == "Any Language")
    {
        strLang = "%";
    }
    else
    {
        strLang = ddlLanguage.SelectedItem.Text;
    }

    using (SqlConnection scCon = new SqlConnection(cString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand scCmd = new SqlCommand("searchPhysician", scCon))
        {
            scCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            scCmd.Parameters.Add("@strProvider", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strProv;
            scCmd.Parameters.Add("@strSpecialty", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strSpec;
            scCmd.Parameters.Add("@strLocation", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strLoca;
            scCmd.Parameters.Add("@strGender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strGend;
            scCmd.Parameters.Add("@strInsurance", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strInsu;
            scCmd.Parameters.Add("@strLanguage", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strLang;

            scCon.Open();
            scCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //rptSearchResult datasource = result from the above store procedure query
            //lblCount.Text = rptSearchResult.Items.Count
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve the following without submitting other buttons in the page:

```
    //rptSearchResult datasource = result from the above store procedure query
    //lblCount.Text = rptSearchResult.Items.Count
```

I also would like the URL of the page to have the query string after the result has been shown:

Example: `www.mypage.com/search.aspx?name=any provider&specialty=any specialty&location=any location`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you can **Redirect** any one who click on **btnSearch** to current page with some **Query Strings**. and then in **Page_Load** you call **Search** function that reads **Query Strings** and bind **rptSearchResult**. I hope you get what I mean...

```
string cString;
SqlConnection Conn;
string sqlCode = "";
string strGender = "";
int rowCount = 0;
string strProv, strSpec, strLoca, strGend, strInsu, strLang;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cString = ""; //my connection string
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulatePhysician();
        PopulateLocation();
        PopulateSpecialty();
        PopulateInsurance();
        PopulateLanguage();

        Search();
    }
}

public void lbSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/search.aspx?name={0}&specialty={1}&location={2}", ddlProvider.SelectedItem.Text, ddlSpecialty.SelectedItem.Text, ddlLocation.SelectedItem.Text));
}

public void Search()
{
    Conn = new SqlConnection(cString);
    Conn.Open();

    strGender = Request.QueryString["Gender"];

    if (Request.QueryString["Provider"] == "Any Provider")
    {
        strProv = "%";
    }
    else
    {
        strProv = Request.QueryString["Provider"];
    }
    if (Request.QueryString["Specialty"] == "Any Specialty")
    {
        strSpec = "%";
    }
    else
    {
        strSpec = Request.QueryString["Specialty"];
    }
    if (Request.QueryString["Location"] == "Any Location")
    {
        strLoca = "%";
    }
    else
    {
        strLoca = Request.QueryString["Location"];
    }
    if (Request.QueryString["Gender"] == "Any Gender")
    {
        strGend = "%";
    }
    else
    {
        strGend = Request.QueryString["Gender"];
    }
    if (Request.QueryString["Insurance"] == "Any Insurance")
    {
        strInsu = "%";
    }
    else
    {
        strInsu = Request.QueryString["Insurance"];
    }
    if (Request.QueryString["Language"] == "Any Language")
    {
        strLang = "%";
    }
    else
    {
        strLang = Request.QueryString["Language"];
    }

    using (SqlConnection scCon = new SqlConnection(cString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand scCmd = new SqlCommand("searchPhysician", scCon))
        {
            scCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            scCmd.Parameters.Add("@strProvider", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strProv;
            scCmd.Parameters.Add("@strSpecialty", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strSpec;
            scCmd.Parameters.Add("@strLocation", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strLoca;
            scCmd.Parameters.Add("@strGender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strGend;
            scCmd.Parameters.Add("@strInsurance", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strInsu;
            scCmd.Parameters.Add("@strLanguage", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strLang;

            scCon.Open();
            scCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //rptSearchResult datasource = result from the above store procedure query
            //lblCount.Text = rptSearchResult.Items.Count
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to call `Search()` if it's the first time loading :/

Comment: One thing, the URL changes, but the DropDownList sets everything back to default which I don't want. Also, I would like to call `SEARCH()` only if I clicked Search in the page.

Comment: for first time: you should check queryStrings, if there isn't any so don't call Search.
for set DropDownLists you should check queryString in Page_Load too and decide to choose one option upon queryStrings data

Comment: Will this do? `if (Request.QueryString["provider"] != "")`

Comment: **if (Request.QueryString["provider"] != null && Request.QueryString["provider"] != "")** is better

Comment: Do you know how I can prevent the DropDown to reset to default?

Comment: you mean that select first item?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w5wf6sz1/ (I modified it based on what your said, now it just refreshes the page with the URL but doesn't perform the search.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63245/discussion-between-mohamad-shiralizadeh-and-searchforknowledge).

Comment: The issue I am having is because the query string is not added to the URL after click, it still says ANY PROVIDER

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things.

1. Add `OnClick` handler for `asp:Button` like this.

`<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />`

2. Rename `public void lbSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` to `protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Earlier `lbSearch_Click` event was bound to `linkbutton` , and i am suggesting to rename this to suggested one, so that on submit button click , those code blocks which were executing for `linkbutton` will now be executed for `Search` button click.